# How to select the nth child of an element and assign a click() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving an index number (for the sake of the example var index).
I have a some 'li'. I need to assign the click() function to the 'li' that is located on the index position. 
i.e. If I have index = 1, I need to get the first 'li' clicked.

I tried many things but most of them give me error.
Any approach is OK as long as I can assign click() to the li that has the same number as the value in index.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <ul class="product-gallery-dots product-dots">
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="navigation10" id="slick-slide10">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">1</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation11" id="slick-slide11" class="">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">2</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation12" id="slick-slide12" class="">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">3</button>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <ul class="product-gallery-dots product-dots">
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="navigation20" id="slick-slide20">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">1</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation21" id="slick-slide21" class="">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">2</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation22" id="slick-slide22" class="">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">3</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

<script>

var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('product-gallery-dots product-dots');
var index = 2; //could be any other number
ul[0].children().eq(index).click(); //ERROR

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that the problem also has to do with the fact that the var 'ul' in this case is a HTMLUListElement when I apply a[0] and for that reason, I can't assign events.

Answer (score 1):

you can only call jQuery methods on jQuery objects - at the moment you have done your selection using vanilla JS, and so `ul` is a JS object not a jQuery one. Either replace `var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('product-gallery-dots product-dots');` with `var ul = $(".product-gallery-dots.product-dots").get(0)` and keep the rest of the code the same, or you could try

```
$(".product-gallery-dots.product-dots").eq(0).children().eq(index).click()
```

Comment: The issue is that I have two objects with the same class name. So the code that you wrote above will affect both. I need only one to be affected. That's why I thought about using brackets [] but didn't work.

Comment: it's still giving me this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).children is not a function

Comment: my mistake, replace `get`s with `eq`s

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass in an arbitrary list of numbers (the rest operator (`...`) will treat list of numbers as an array):

   ```
   // positions = 2, 5, 9, 44, 0, 7
   function clickButton(...positions) {...
   ```
2. Target the button within each list item:

   ```
   $('li button')
   ```
3. Collect all of them into a jQuery collection then convert that into an array:

   ```
   const buttons = $('li button').toArray();
   ```
4. In each iteration of a `for...of` loop get the current `[index, button]` by destructuring each entry returned by `buttons.entries()`...

   ```
   for (let [index, button] of buttons.entries()) {...
   ```
5. ...if a number from the parameters (`...positions`) matches an `index` number +1 <sup>✱</sup>....

   ```
   if (positions.includes(index + 1)) {...
   ```
6. ...click the current button programmatically.

   ```
   button.click();
   ```
7. For demonstration purposes a click handler has been registered to each button to show which buttons were clicked.

   ✱ <sub>In most collections like array, NodeList, jQuery collection, etc. they have a 0-index which means there's an offset of -1 of a normal count. You should really get in that mindset of counting collections starting from 0 if you plan on programming more in the future.</sub>

   ```js
   function clickButton(...positions) {
     const buttons = $('li button').toArray();
     for (let [index, button] of buttons.entries()) {
       if (positions.includes(index + 1)) {
         button.click();
       }
     }
   }

   $('li button').on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).toggleClass('on off');
   });

   clickButton(0, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 15);
   ```

   ```css
   ul {
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none
   }

   button {
     display: block;
     width: 5ch;
     cursor: pointer
   }

   .on {
     color: #fff;
     background: #000
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <ul>
     <li><button class='off'>1</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>2</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>3</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>4</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>5</button></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
     <li><button class='off'>6</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>7</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>8</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>9</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>10</button></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
     <li><button class='off'>11</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>12</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>13</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>14</button></li>
     <li><button class='off'>15</button></li>
   </ul>


   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```